# VS2010 and Point Cloud Library with CMake

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to compile a demo project, but when I used CMake I keep running into errors for generating the project. Currently I'm stuck at the CMake output of:

> CMake Error: File C:/Users/Thomas/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/PCL1/pcl_config.h.in does not exist.
>   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:232 (configure_file):
>     configure_file Problem configuring file
>
> Could NOT find GTest (missing:  GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY) 
>   Tests will not be built: GTest was not found.
>   CMake Error at cmake/pcl_utils.cmake:291 (list):
>     list sub-command REMOVE_ITEM requires list to be present.
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     CMakeLists.txt:247 (topological_sort)
>
> CMake Error at cmake/pcl_utils.cmake:341 (message):
>     list_length must be at least equal to 1
>   Call Stack (most recent call first):
>     cmake/pcl_utils.cmake:386 (fill_list)
>     CMakeLists.txt:248 (sort_relative)

I never created a PCL_config.h file and looking at the CMakeList.txt implies that the file is created by CMake itself. Further, I've never used GTest and have no idea what it does.

Any ideas?

Comment: GTest == Google Test: http://code.google.com/p/googletest/

Comment: I agree that from what you posted PCL_config.h should be generated from CMake. Also if you do not use GTest is there an option to turn off unit testing?

Comment: Yes, `BUILD_tests` and `BUILD_global_tests` flags can be turned off in cmake

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

1. Get the precompiled version of PCL 1.6.0 from the official PCL website.
2. It comes with all the dependencies, just make sure the setup runs without any errors.
3. Install CMAKE 2.8. or higher.
4. Follow the instructions about compiling and running PCL code with CMake from any of the PCL tutorials.
5. You may need to uninstall everything and do a fresh install before the above mentioned steps.

Let us know if it works.